# Cut audio without snap to frame

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio

I'd like to cut a audio to an exact point, and this might be in between of the related frames. Is there a way to maybe "cut" or "slide" an audio track to between frames?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I believe there is, because I enabled it by accident once, but I don’t remember how to get to it. I just remember the term “show sub-frames”

Comment: It had to do with the scene frame settings, because it primarily affected the current cursor position time.

Comment: Thanks, this helps putting the playhead just anywhere between frames - which comes pretty close to what I need. But then while splitting, it will still split at the frame level unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, because I think the sequences can only range from one frame to another. Or could you possibly move the sequence in-between frames? Then you might be able to move the point where to cut directly at the frame position, cut it and then move it back where it belongs?

Comment: you could change the fps just the time to cut the audio file, but it's not a long-term solution